# How does multi-line .method() syntax work?

Tags: java

I'm curious about how Java reads something like the following code.

```
return arrayList.stream() 
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue) 
    .toArray();
```

Code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-an-element-at-specific-index-from-an-array-in-java/

Is this the equivalent of putting everything on the same line, but more readable, or does each return to the next line changes the priority or order or execution ?

I'd expect the former, but I still struggle with stream and map

(Also, how should you indent this ?)

Comment: you could write `arrayList` then 5 gazillion spaces and then `.stream()` and it would result in the same.

Comment: It is equivalent. Whitespace here (including new lines) is not relevant. The "line" runs until the `;`.

Comment: Whitespace and line breaks are not significant in Java, so the code is exactly equivalent to the same code all on one line without spaces.

Comment: Statements are semicolon-separated in Java. White spaces like that are almost meaningless and ignored.

Comment: It is the same as it all being on one line. The semicolon indicates the end of the statement, so the whitespace doesn't matter.

Comment: Are you really asking about `stream` and `map`, e.g. maybe the order rather than the whitespace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extra whitespace is never significant in Java, you can always put as many linebreaks or spaces anywhere you like and it will never affect the execution of the code.

So this:

```
return arrayList.stream() 
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue) 
    .toArray();
```

Is equal to this:

```
return arrayList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

And this:

```
return
         arrayList.       stream()   .    mapToInt(     Integer :: intValue) .
                            toArray    (     ) ;
```